# Div with top left and right corner same color with linear gradient

Tags: css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I want to have the following UI by CSS. I tried using the following but it doesn't produce the output that I expected.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 20%, white 20%);
```

[image]

(*Black borders are not required. They are for just boundaries*)

Can anyone give any suggestions or solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: @vucko, I tried background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black 20%, white 20%); Can i have any example related to this? I am new bee to this.

Comment: Are the black borders also required (or) are they present in image only for marking boundaries?

Comment: Black borders are not required. They are for just boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements:

```css
#foo{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

#foo::before, #foo::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

#foo::before{
  left: 0;
  border-width: 200px 70px 0 0;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}

#foo::after{
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 70px 200px 0;
  border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha4xfvxz/)

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved using a couple of `linear-gradient` background images. All that we have to do is create the gradients with the required size and position them on the left-top and right-top of the element.

The output produced by linear gradients is responsive and one advantage is that it doesn't require any extra pseudo-elements (so they can be used for other purposes). The main drawback is the browser support for gradients. They work in all modern browsers but do not work in IE9-. The other problem is that gradients are known for producing jagged edges as the dimensions of the container become large but that wouldn't be a big problem as long as the *borders are not required*.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent calc(50% - 1px), rgb(0, 162, 232) calc(50% + 1px)), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), rgb(0, 162, 232) calc(50% + 1px));
  background-size: 30% 85%;
  background-position: left top, right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 2s;  /* just for demo */
}

div:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

We can also add the borders if required by playing around a bit more with the gradients.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent calc(50% - 1px), black 50%, black calc(50% + 1px), rgb(0, 162, 232) calc(50% + 2px)), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), black 50%, black calc(50% + 1px), rgb(0, 162, 232) calc(50% + 2px));
  background-size: 30% 85%;
  background-position: left top, right top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 2s;
  /* just for demo */
  border: 2px solid black;
}
div:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Does this code support in all browsers/version? If any issue can you please let me know.

Comment: @getty: It would not work only in IE9, IE8 (as they don't support gradients). Should work in all other browsers though some older versions of Chrome, Firefox would require the `-webkit-` or `-moz-` prefixes. You can find the browser support chart [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

Comment: Love your solution even better :)